# How to increase a usestate number inside a div in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

I have a useState inside div, I want to update the counter beacuse I want to get another img url from exArr array. is there a way to update counter inside a div?

```
let exArr = [];
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div className="menRight">

            {
                products.filter(product => product.productGender.includes('Kids')).slice(0, showProducts).map(product => (                    
                    <div className="menRightCard">
                        <Link to={`/productBuy?id=${product.productImageFolder}`}>
                            <div className="menRightCardimg">
                                <i className="far fa-heart"></i>
                                <img src={exArr[counter]} alt="" />
  /* I WANT TO CHANGE HERE */   { setCounter(counter => counter + 1) }

                            </div>
                            <div className="menRightCardInfo">
                                <p className="productInfo">
                                    {product.productName}
                                </p>
                                <p className="productPrice">
                                    €{product.productPrice}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                    </div>

                    
    
    ))
            }       
            <div className="loadMore">
                <button onClick={showMoreItems}>Load More Products</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: what do you want to be the trigger to update the useState hook?

Comment: there is a map, when it's in the first index counter should be 0, when it's in second, it should be 1 ... I try to do something like this, because I don't want to show same photos in every map.

Comment: Why need a counter at all? If the goal is to have an index [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) already provides it. Have you considered using `.map((product, index) => /**/)`

Comment: omg thank you so much. it worked!